# C++ Library for session management?

Tags: c++, session, cookies, url-rewriting

This is in reference to question [How to maintain sessions with C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005242/how-to-maintain-sessions-with-c-code)

Is there a C++ library (like Boost) available to manage sessions for web based CGI applications?

How feasible is it to make use of Cookies and URL Rewriting in C++ code for web based CGI applications?

Comment: are you writing the server from scratch or are you integrating with an existing server via some sort of plugin architecture?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it, but I came across this:

http://rudeserver.com/session/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another link:

http://www.webtoolkit.eu

I've never tried it (because I'm not programming webapps), but a fellow student of mine uses Wt and loves it.

Answer (score 0):

One option is use of session variables. I am not very sure that they will work with C++ but they are one of the best option of session management in java and are always 
preferable over cookies as cookies are written on the client browser and you may have to 
compromise with the sensitive data security.

Sachin

Comment: use of session variables is not recommendable.