# Sessions like PHP in C++?

Tags: php, c++, session

Is it possible to use something like sessions like the ones in PHP in C++?

In PHP they're used like

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $value;
```

I really want to make the same application using C++ as PHP...requires a run-time parser.

My application written in PHP uses sessions so that i can fetch some stuff from a website(numbers) and store the value in a SESSION varible which i call last to compare it to the new value when the page is reloaded.

I'd rather have the same functionality in C++.

Seeing as this is going nowhere i am going to provide the PHP code

```
<?php
session_start();

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://dashjr.org/~luke-jr/programs/bitcoin/pool/balances.json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

echo 'Last BTC: '.$_SESSION['last'].'<br>';

$obj = json_decode($result,true);
echo 'Current BTC: ';
$new = (int)$obj["1Hy5h24yBYKtQ1vNGaxY5rBJSEuTiMkBkx"]["balance"]/100000000;
echo $new;

if((int)$_SESSION['last'] < $new)
{
    echo '<br><br>You earned more';
}
else
{
    echo '<br><br>You earned less';
}

$_SESSION['last'] = $obj["1Hy5h24yBYKtQ1vNGaxY5rBJSEuTiMkBkx"]["balance"]/100000000;



unset($result,$obj);

?>
```

I need to port *that* to C++.

Comment: Are you trying to write a web application using C++?

Comment: Definitely not. Just a small "parser"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005242/how-to-maintain-sessions-with-c-code

Comment: It will use cURL to fetch some data from a website. That's the only web part of it.

Answer (score 1):

This makes no sense, PHP sessions are a kludge because the process does not survive one HTTP request to the next. I really dunno what do you want to achieve here. Maybe http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/interprocess.html this?

Comment: It works. I set the session varible in script and print it on the next reload before i get the new value thus allowing me to make a previous and current variables to compare stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If your data requirements are small you could just store the value in a cookie which the caller will pass back to the C++ CGI program when it invokes it again.

EDIT:  As this isn't a webapp, just use regular C++ IO functions to preserve the data, either in a file, a registry key (for Windows) or, if you've got extensive data requirements, an embedded database like Sqlite.

EDIT: If it's just sitting in a loop, and you don't need to preserve the value from one invocation to another (i.e. across program restarts), just store the value in a different variable.  You can just use an [STL hashmap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) as the "SESSION" if you want to use name/value pairs.  Or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: It will be a simple console application, doing a loop every X seconds. I need to store the previous data from the cURL fetch and compare them to the new data. In PHP i use SESSIONS. In C++, the variable will be overwritten.

Comment: since the console app will not be close and restarted, maybe you can just keep it in a regular variable

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a "session" as in a "PHP session" only makes sense if you are doing server-side Web development. C++ was designed to be as general-purpose as possible (whether that goal was achieved is a completely different story), so it does not natively support any concept related to any specific application. Which, in your particular case, means C++ has no native concept of a "session", of course.

Of course, *in theory*, you could do PHP-style Web development in C++, including using PHP-like sessions. But you would have to either (1) use some framework exposing PHP-like session functionality, which I doubt anyone has ever developed; or (2) implement said framework yourself, which would be *really* inconvenient. And there would no tangible advantage you could get in return for your inconvenience: The main reasons why people use C++ these days are (1) performance is too critical to use a higher-level language, and (2) compatibility with other systems written in C++ is a requirement. (1) does not apply, because, in most cases, a Web application's response time is dominated by the time it takes to transmit messages across the network, even for Web applications deployed in an Intranet. The time it takes a Web server to process a request, however complex, is often minuscule in comparison. And (2) does not apply because systems interoperating on the Web are developed following standards that ensure the technologies underlying these systems do not matter.

Most people saying they need to implement their applications in C++ are people who have already implemented said applications in their languages of choice (or their bosses' languages of choice) and found performance problems. In my experience, most software-caused performance problems arise from the fact applications are not properly designed and/or implemented with scalability in mind. For a Web application, things like minimizing the amount of server trips (each time a particular value/object/whatever has to be sent across the network in order to get a response back) are the kind of design decisions that can meaningfully affect performance.

In short: If performance problems are the reason why you want to implement this application in C++, you better analyze each part of your current PHP system, determine which one(s) are causing the performance issues, and redesign and reimplement them.

Comment: I want to make it in C++ as php is not only a quick way, but requires apache and php to be installed. One need not be bothered with installing those if he wishes to use my application.

Comment: @dikidera: Here is this thing about Open Source that I like: You can have a peek at a progarm's source code to get an idea of how complex its inner workings are, and to measure your chances of reimplementing it within a given time framework. So read Apache's and PHP's sources, and then tell me you are going to reimplement that by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> PHP...requires a run-time parser.

Nope, install apc or any other compiled code cache, and php is only parsed once. Of course the generated bytecode is still interpreted...

On big frameworks (lots of code) parsing time can be a lot longer than actual script execution, so this cuts down the page times quite a lot.

Comment: The reason is, i want to depoly this application(which in php is just 15-20 lines of code) to the general public. But installing PHP for just a simple script by every person that wants to use it is....a hassle

Comment: >> But installing PHP for just a simple script by every person that wants to use it << ??  It just needs to be installed on the website hosting the application.  Are you saying that this isn't a webapp but you're just using PHP as a scripting language for a local application?

Comment: There will no hosting of the application. This script is for the general public..released with source and everything.
I initally wrote it for myself as i know how it would work in PHP.
But if users want to use it as well for themselves, i can't ask them to install PHP,Apache for just 15-20 lines of code. C++ on the other hand will be compiled and rest is left for Windows to handle